# When I upload my website to smartasp.net I get the error: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, database-connection

I've built a website with asp.net & c# that was working well in localhost but when I uploaded it to smartasp.net it is showing this error:

> SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

The connection string to the database is:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

And the database is located in App_Data folder. I've tried to change the connection to:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=**App_Data**\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

but I get the same problem.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

This error happens if the SQL Named Instance cannot be connected to.

Ensure that the .\SQLExpress instance is expected on the smartasp.net site and that the service is running.

Ask the site admin/support if it is supported and what is the instance name.

Comment: what will happen if I remove SQLEXPRESS

Comment: with ./SQLExpress you're saying that you're connecting to a SQL Server on your localhost (smartasp.net web server) and a named instance called SQLExpress. if you remove SQLExpress then you're connecting to the default instance on the local web server. typically hosted web servers dont have a local SQL Server. So ask your hosting provider the SQL Server IP/Name, so that you can replace the dot with that in the connectiion string.